# JSTL gt not returning correct value

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a problem with some JSTL not evaluating a 'gt' as expected, some code:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${param.totalPages > pageLinkCount}">
```

The JSP never renders the content of that when block, rather it always renders the  block content. Something about the test is failing.

I tried a solution found [here for a similar looking problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688636/jsp-jstl-2-10-evaluates-to-true) where the solution involved adding a declaration to tell JSP/JSTL engine that the vars are Longs (they are for me too)...

```
<%@ attribute name="currentPage" required="true" type="java.lang.Long" %>
```

... but I found that error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/includes/pagination.jsp(4,13) &lt;%@ attribute directive can only be used in a tag file
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:132)
```

The test is in a JSP include included like this:

```
<jsp:include page="../includes/pagination.jsp" >
    <jsp:param value="${pages}" name="totalPages"/> 
    ....other params
```

Some test values output into the html:

param.TotalPages: 171

TotalPages: 171 (local JSTL var I tried assigning the value of param.totalPages)

Current: 64

BeginPage: 1

EndPage: 171

PageLinkCount: 3

Comment: What's the output of `${param.totalPages}` and of `${pageLinkCount}`? I find it strange for the total pages to be a request parameter.

Comment: totalPages does output a numeric value which is correct, the pagination jsp is included in other pages thus: <jsp:include page="../includes/pagination.jsp" ><jsp:param value="${pages}" name="totalPages"/> ....other params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from the

```
<jsp:include
```

style include to the

```
<@include
```

directive, changed the params to c:set var instead and now it seems to work.

So as much as I'd prefer to use jsp:include style of including pages it seems params are handled not quite as I expected so I'll stick to @ directive style includes for now.

Answer (score 0):

This error scenario is typically a typo, lower case vs upper case, or similar:

- *param.totalPages* vs *param.TotalPages*
- *pageLinkCount* vs *PageLinkCount*

Verify this, as the JSTL variable names are not case sensitive.